# new to web scraping - is it possible to locate css images using path?

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

I am new to webscraping and I am lack at even the basic webscraping/web-selectors concepts.
Is it possible to locate CSS images using XPath (using selenium)? I know that there is a way to locate html image element by xpath, but I am not sure if this is the case in CSS...

Thank you,

Comment: The issue here is that an element's style information is not, in itself, an element on the page. CSS decorators are associated with existing elements (usually through some mix of ID and class attributes or the page's hierarchy). Are you trying to get a list of elements decorated in a particular way? Or trying to inspect the CSS itself?

Comment: hello, I am just trying to extract information about images on certain websites, such as image height/width/title/position, etc. is it possible to use xpath to come up with a full list of images that is contained in a certain website?

Comment: that is, the full list of images including html AND CSS images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. XPath operates on XML like structures, so you can browse the HTML structure (if it has appropriate end tags or is at least sanitized), and find all the `<img>` tags.

However, CSS images are contained within a separate string file that doesn't really convert well into an XML-like structure. As such, ou couldn't use XPath to get all the images on a webpage.

Comment: Hello, I am only interested in the CSS images that are listed as part of internal style sheet - wouldn't this work? `listOfimages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img'or "//*[contains(@style, 'background-image')]")`?

Comment: I think you mean "in-line" CSS. It will work, but that query will return the element that has the `background-image`, and only if its declared using `background-image` and not `background`. Also, getting the actual value of the background-image value from the inline string would be difficult.

Comment: I meant internal style sheet (as oppose to external style sheet). but you are right, the code wouldn't capture the image that has attribute `backgroud` instead of `background-image`...thank you for your input though